# Can we change the modern page's title's font color

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

I created a new modern page, and i am trying to change the font color for the page title is this possible? if this is not possible , then can i hide the page title completely and instead of this to add a text web page which acts as the title and control its color?

Comment: Do you want to change the font color for all modern pages or only particular pages? If you want to do it for all the pages then you can apply custom CSS by creating SPFx application customizer.

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am trying to find a way to allow end users to change the page titles to whatever color they want,, not necessary the same color... i am trying to find something similar to the modern text editor web part, where you select a text and change its color,size, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could craete a js file to read the text editor web part value and set the title style with the value.
Then you could use SPFX extension to upload js file to SPO.

https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss(demo on add CSS file,you could change it to add JS file)